# Input button never appears when javascript detects form completed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a register page using HTML, CSS and JS and Java servlet etc. I have a monitorer() function which checks if the user has finished inputting everything before making the register button visible. But now everything works, but somewhere am getting screwed over and the button never comes back..

### my button in reg.html :

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btnSub" id="btnReg" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
```

### javascript function monitorer()

```
function monitorer() {
var btnReg = document.getElementById("btnReg");
btnReg.style.visibility = "hidden";
var flag = true;

if (document.getElementById("fname").value.length >= 3) {
    if (document.getElementById("lname").value.length >= 3) {
        if (valiDate(document.getElementById("dob"))) {
            if (document.getElementById("USN").value.length == 10) {
                if (document.getElementById("passw").value.length > 5) {
                    var ticks = document.getElementsByClassName("checker"), i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < ticks.length; i++) {
                        if (ticks.item(i).innerHTML == "&#x2714;") {
                            alert("i val = " + i);
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            flag = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                flag = false;
                document.getElementById("USN").focus();
            }
        } else {
            flag = false;
            document.getElementById("dob").focus();
        }
    } else {
        flag = false;
        document.getElementById("lname").focus();
    }
} else {
    flag = false;
    document.getElementById("fname").focus();
}

if (flag == true) {
    btnReg.style.visibility = "visible";
} else if(flag == false) {
    btnReg.style.visibility = "hidden";
}}
```

And to help you get as good a picture as you can, a screenshot

[image]

See - all the ticks are there, the first name, last name etc are having value.length >=3 but still the register button doesn't show..

Also, I have put the monitorer() method in every input's "onBlur", "onChange" events.

Here is a link to my html file >>> [reg.html](http://pastebin.com/d81R1TiA)

and please let me know if i can improve anything?

Comment: have you tried debugging every conditional's block with a `console.log`/`alert`?

Comment: alert(flag) value.. at last and see your output is true/false.

Comment: ohh.. thanks, ill try that, i have been trying all debugging methods.. except that.. like alert('fname'), alert('lname'), etc... but coudlnt understand.. what monitorer does is check everything, so if all the fields are all right, then the button should become visible...

Comment: also i dont think it is going into the for loop to get ticks data, so i think i need a workaround for that.

Comment: please change your title..

Comment: what title?? question title?

Comment: Holy mother of `if` blocks.

Comment: :) Parent/Guardian - I've been burned by expressions of frustration like that, careful!